# How to format #'s in Google Charts to have commas

Tags: google-visualization

I'm using the Google Visualization API, aka [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/), and I'm trying to get the numbers to show ,'s in them.

My data:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Device', 'Views'],
  ['Mobile', 1456632],
  ['Tablet', 6]
]);
```

Chart initialization:

```
var myChart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('myChart'));
myChart.draw(data, { title: 'My pie chart' });
```

On the pie chart, if you hover over the slices, it shows `1456632` for the Mobile slice. Can I have it show `1,456,632` ? I've tried passing in strings and not numbers in the `arrayToDataTable` to define my `data`, but it needs numbers. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use google formatter:

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat(
  {negativeColor: 'red', negativeParens: true, groupingSymbol:','});
formatter.format(data, 1);
```

Read more about [NumberFormatter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#numberformatter)

Comment: I use this hack to format every number column:            

for (i = 1; i < chartData[0].length; i++) {
  formatter.format(data, i);
}